# BadRequestException: Lex is unable to access the Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-lex

Hi I am working building chatbot using Aws Lex and lambda.
I am using lexmodelbuildingservice.putIntent API to create new Intent. But when i test my Lambda function. I get below error:

```
BadRequestException: Lex is unable to access the Lambda function arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:function:chatBotResponse in the context of intent arn:aws:lex:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:intent:BenefitsTwotwo:$LATEST.  Please check the resource-based policy on the function
```

I am using below code in my params:

```
fulfillmentActivity: {
        codeHook: {
            uri: "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:function:chatBotResponse",
            messageVersion: "1.0"
         },
     type: "CodeHook"     
    }
```

Can anybody please tell me how to access and enable lambda arn using nodejs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> BadRequestException
>
> - Request validation failed, there is no usable message in the context, or the bot build failed, is still in progress, or contains unbuilt changes.
> - HTTP Status Code: 400

Did your bot completely built? or contains unbuilt changes?